# Insert or update a row using MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have two MySQL tables: `sms` and `consumption`. The `sms` table contain all transactions while the `consumption` table contain the sum of sms consumed.

My goal is to be able to now the actual consumption for a day, so I need just to check directly on `consumption` table.
For it, I'm trying to create a trigger that will verify:

1. if for day 1 there is no row in `consumption` table, then insert a new row
2. if there is already a row for day 1, then update it

Here my code that doesn't work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_new_sms_sent
AFTER INSERT ON sms
FOR EACH ROW
    SET @k = (SELECT id FROM consumption WHERE period = NEW.simple_date);
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(@k) THEN
            INSERT INTO consumption (system_id, period, credit, sms)
            VALUES (NEW.system_id, NEW.simple_date, NEW.used_credit, NEW.sms_count);
        ELSE
            UPDATE consumption SET credit = credit + New.used_credit, sms = sms + NEW.sms_count WHERE (system_id = NEW.system_id) AND (period = NEW.simple_date);
    END CASE
```

How can I do?

Comment: What is not working? Your trigger or you could not add a trigger?

Comment: Please add table structures for both the table.

Comment: @money, I'm getting error when I execute the above code

Comment: Try to put you script between :   
delimiter $$  
// your script // 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_new_sms_sent
AFTER INSERT ON sms
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT;

    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO num_rows FROM consumption
    WHERE system_id = NEW.system_id AND period = NEW.simple_date;

    IF num_rows = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO consumption (system_id, period, credit, sms)
        VALUES (NEW.system_id, NEW.simple_date, NEW.used_credit, NEW.sms_count);
    ELSE
        UPDATE consumption
        SET credit = credit + NEW.used_credit, sms = sms + NEW.sms_count
        WHERE system_id = NEW.system_id AND period = NEW.simple_date;
    END IF;

  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please note that you must use `system_id = NEW.system_id` in your `WHERE` condition  of `SELECT` query. Otherwise with the solution that you have selected, it is possible that you will get count > 0 but your `UPDATE` will fail if record with that `id` is not present in `consumption`.

Comment: I understand that if I add `system_id = NEW.system_id` in my `WHERE` clause, it will not give me `TOO_MANY_RECORDS` exception. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_new_sms_sent AFTER INSERT ON sms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_CNT INT;
      SELECT id INTO VAR_CNT FROM consumption WHERE period = NEW.simple_date AND system_id = NEW.system_id;

      IF VAR_CNT = 0 THEN  
        INSERT INTO consumption (system_id, period, credit, sms)
        VALUES (NEW.system_id, NEW.simple_date, NEW.used_credit, NEW.sms_count);
      ELSE
        UPDATE consumption SET credit = credit + New.used_credit, sms = sms + NEW.sms_count WHERE (system_id = NEW.system_id) AND (period = NEW.simple_date);
      END IF ;

END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Try above query.

Comment: @nekiala Why you did not accept my answer?? Even though i had given it before 28 mins ago..

Comment: Hi @Sagar, your code worked well. I just noticed that when a new row was inserted in `sms` table, the trigger inserted a new row in `consumption` table for the same `period` instead of updating the existing row.

Comment: I just reviewed your answer, the mistake is here: `IF VAR_CNT != 0 THEN INSERT`. It must have been `IF VAR_CNT = 0 THEN INSERT`. Because my goal was : `if there is no row for day 1, then insert, if not, then update`.